# Android Studio Is there a way to create a new activity with only changing 1 word?

Tags: android

I am working on a game collection project for my self. Well it was a school project that I am going to finish and use myself. I am coping and pasting each activity and java page and scrolling though each time changing only the name of the game. I have to add a few lines of code to the manifest and the main activity page as well with the same procedure, but they are not that long. I wanted to know if there was a program or batch file or any way that I can write a simple program that can generate the code changing only the name of the game, or maybe add a var in that spot and change the var which would change the name throughout the code. Below is one of the class for a game named abadox. Now what I am doing is just coping this file and changing everwhere that has the name abadox to say mario. I just wanted to know if there was a easy way to do this instead of having to copy and paste this code a few thousand times to get all the games I want and waste my time. I probably have some code wrong I am pretty much teaching myself and I have it working the way I wanted. I tried to use a database but I could not figure out how to get it to work right. I could have used a database and pulled the files in I know that but wasn't sure how to do it.

```
public class Abadox extends Activity {
    EditText abadoxCopies;
    EditText abadoxBar;
    EditText abadoxCom;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_abadox);

    abadoxCopies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtabadoxCopies);
    abadoxBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtabadoxBor);
    abadoxCom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtabadoxCom);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("abadox", 0);

        String strabadoxcopies = sharedPref.getString("abadoxcopies", "");
        String strabadoxbarrow = sharedPref.getString("abadoxbarrow", "");
        String strabadoxcomment = sharedPref.getString("abadoxcomment", "");

    abadoxCopies.setText(strabadoxcopies);
    abadoxBar.setText(strabadoxbarrow);
    abadoxCom.setText(strabadoxcomment);

    }
    //Save files

public void saveInfo(View view) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("abadox", 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("abadoxcopies", abadoxCopies.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("abadoxbarrow", abadoxBar.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("abadoxcomment", abadoxCom.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
    editor.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NES.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Make an abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

Well Android Studio gives you the option to create so called `File Templates`. You can create one on your own by doing a `Right click on your package -> New -> Edit File Templates`. There you can create a new template by clicking on the green plus. Then add the following

```
public class ${NAME} extends Activity {
    EditText ${var_name}Copies;
    EditText ${var_name}Bar;
    EditText ${var_name}Com;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_${layout});

        ${var_name}Copies = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt${var_name}Copies);
        ${var_name}Bar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt${var_name}Bor);
        ${var_name}Com = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt${var_name}Com);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("${var_name}", 0);

        String strabadoxcopies = sharedPref.getString("${var_name}copies", "");
        String strabadoxbarrow = sharedPref.getString("${var_name}barrow", "");
        String strabadoxcomment = sharedPref.getString("${var_name}comment", "");

        ${var_name}Copies.setText(str${var_name}copies);
        ${var_name}Bar.setText(str${var_name}barrow);
        ${var_name}Com.setText(str${var_name}comment);

    }
    //Save files

    public void saveInfo(View view) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("${var_name}", 0);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("${var_name}copies", ${var_name}Copies.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("${var_name}barrow", ${var_name}Bar.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("${var_name}comment", ${var_name}Com.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NES.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Save it! Afterwards you can see the newly added template in the `New` popup. Once you select it you'll be prompted to enter the class name, var_name and layout.

Other than that I'd say it's not the recommended approach to use the same code in multiple classes just with other names. ;)

Comment: I will try to make a template and see if I can make it work.

Comment: I bought a new gaming keyboard the G510s and i am using the G keys to hold each page so I all I have to do now is hit one key and it puts the all the code on the page.